# When someone says they are peckish does it mean they are hungry or feel like a chicken?

Tags: single-word-requests

The word peck is describing a bird eat. so is the word peckish exclusively for birds? Can you say peckish for a person being hungry as well?

Comment: Peckish: adjective, (Chiefly British Informal.)

somewhat hungry:
By noon we were feeling a bit peckish. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/peckish

Comment: Actually, "peckish" means "about 8.8 liters".

Answer (score 1):

The word peckish is not at all for birds. It can either mean someone who is hungry or someone who is irritable.

_I'm feeling peckish; can I order something?
_sure honey, you can have dust! delicious zero calorie dust.

Source for Irritable: [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/peckish)

Comment: Do you have a source/cite for peckish=irritable? I've not heard that before.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/peckish      and https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/peckish   http://www.dictionary.com/browse/peckish  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peckish    I'm new, I don't know how to add sources. Do you just link?

Comment: That's interesting, it looks as though the irritable version is more US, so being in UK I was unfamiliar with it. If you visit the [help] you should find topics on how to answer, generally people will create a link with the name of the source and quote the relevant text. There are link and quote buttons on the answer box toolbar to assist.

Comment: I would tend to assume "irritable" rather than "hungry" in the US, absent context to the contrary.

Comment: Re adding links, you can [edit](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/404902/edit) (there's a link below your answer)

Comment: I added TFD source and link for you -- you can do the others, if you want.  To make the link concise, put the name of the source in [] and then put the url of the source in () immediately after the right bracket.   You can put in anything you want for the name -- it doesn't have to be the actual name of the source.

Comment: Someone can be irritable from many causes ... being tired,  bored, distracted by a larger problem, or perhaps hungry.  Personally, I think of the word somewhere between the British and American sense.... 'irritable probably because of being hungry'